# Xcode : Adding a project as a build dependency

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, build-dependencies

Im playing around with the [soundcloud api](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/tree/oauth2), in its instructions it says to

- drag SoundCloudAPI.xcodeproj into your project
- add it as a build dependency

I can drag the project in pretty easily, but how does one accomplish the next step?

Comment: Does this work as of the latest version of xCode? I am having problems that I never had before with this, it simply adds the file, not the project.

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question. I have not looked at this in a while, however, in the latest version of xCode you have the concept of a workspace which can consist of multiple projects, look into that.

Comment: **[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726000/xcode-4-2-and-using-a-static-library-causing-problems?answertab=votes#tab-top)** are some great step-by-step instructions on how to add static library dependencies in more recent versions of Xcode.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I met the same problem. Then I found the reason for my problem is that the lib project is already added into some other workspace. So I copied the lib project folder, and added the copied project into the workspace I want to work on. Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII make sure the project you're trying to add is not open in XCode. If it's open in XCode, it will only add the .xcodeproj file, not the whole project.

Comment: @Wonder Dog: Correct!, this solved my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 4.2 how include one project into another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370518/xcode-4-2-how-include-one-project-into-another-one)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To add it as a dependency do the following:

- Highlight the added project in your file explorer within xcode.  In the directory browser window to the right it should show a file with a .a extension.  There is a checkbox under the target column (target icon), check it.
- Right-Click on your Target (under the targets item in the file explorer) and choose Get Info
- On the general tab is a Direct Dependencies section.  Hit the plus button
- Choose the project and click Add Target

Comment: What is the 1st step for? As I can still do the following three steps without doing it.

Comment: any idea what that first step does?

Comment: This links the project(s) to yours. This tells the linker where symbols that are only defined in that project exist and prevents you from getting "undefined symbol" linker errors.

Comment: That's weird. Xcode does not let me add a Direct Dependency. What should I do?

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work. The frameworks I need are still in red as if they are missing.

Comment: These instructions confuse me, as I'm pretty sure they're for an older Xcode version. See @filitchp's answer for a link to instructions that work with Xcode 5.

Comment: Remember to close the .xcodeproj you're trying to add if you had it open in Xcode already. You cannot drill down into the file structure nor add the .framework of the nested project if the same project is already open in another screen. If you close both instances of Xcode and only reopen one project it'll work.

Comment: Just realised the value of the quote "A picture is worth thousand words" - After staring at the answer and Xcode back to back for 30 mins. :(

Answer (score 14):

Tough one for a newbie like me - here is a screenshot that describes it.
Xcode 10.2.1

[image]

Comment: Nice, same for `Xcode 12`!! just drag your `*.xcodeproj` file, deselect copy option, and add it as dependency with `+` button (which can be found with steps the screen-shot shows).

Answer (score 13):

1. Select your project in the navigator on left.
2. Open up the drawer in the middle pane and select your target.
3. Select Build Phases
4. Target Dependencies is an option at that point.

Answer (score 4):

Under `TARGETS` in your project, right-click on your project target *(should be the same name as your project)* and choose `GET INFO`, then on `GENERAL` tab you will see `DIRECT DEPENDENCIES`, simply click the `[+]` and select `SoundCloudAPI`.

Answer (score 3):

Just close the Project you want to add , then drag and drop the file .

Answer (score 3):

**Xcode add a project as a dependency**

Xcode 10

1. drag-n-drop a project into another project - is called `cross-project references`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57713098/4770877)
2. add the added project as a build dependency - is called `Explicit dependency`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57835356/4770877)

```
//Xcode 10
Build Phases -> Target Dependencies -> + Add items 

//Xcode 11
Build Phases -> Dependencies -> + Add items
```

In `Choose items to add:` dialog you will see only targets from your project and the sub-project

[image]

Comment: Cannot find Build Phases -> Target Dependencies but instead i can see Build Phases -> Dependencies in xcode 11.3

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced with the same problem. 
As the result of the first run I got next error:

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'SDKProjectName*/*SDKProjectName.h'
>   file not found.

But before running, I, obviously, added my SDK into the demo project, just drag&drop **.xcodeproj** file into my test project's source tree. After that, I moved into *Build Phases* tab in setting of the main xcodeproj file (of the demo) and added my SDK as target dependency and embed framework into corresponding tabs.

But at the result, I got an error above!

So, the problem was into empty line on the **Header Search Paths** option. I just wrote `"../**"` as value for this key and project compiled successfully. So, after that, you can add `#include <SDKName/SDKName.h>` into any project, which includes this SDK.

ps. My test app was created into root SDK folder.