# Build dependencies and static libraries in Xcode 3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, soundcloud

I'm trying to get the example project for an SoundCloud API wrapper working using XCode 3. There are some [few basic instructions at the start](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper), but I'm having trouble:

QuickStart

In your terminal:

- git clone
- git://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper.git
- SoundCloudAPI cd SoundCloudAPI git
  submodule update --recursive --init

In your Xcode project:

- drag SoundCloudAPI.xcodeproj into your project
- add it as a build dependency
- add the static library as
  a liked target
- add "[relative path to
  SoundCloudAPI]/Sources/SoundCloudAPI"
  to your header search path in the
  build settings
- you can also include
  the OAuth2Client headers by adding
  "[relative path to
  SoundCloudAPI]/Outsourced/OAuth2Client/Sources/OAuth2Client"
  too (although you might not need
  them)

I've completely ignored the part before In Your Xcode project. I think I've done everything correctly to add the build dependency [following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219054/xcode-adding-a-project-as-a-build-dependency), the frameworks are still marked in red as if they were missing. Any advice?

Also the three points after that are also not very clear? Could someone explain these in a bit more detail? For example, where is the header search path? and where are the build settings?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you using Xcode 3 or Xcode 4?

Comment: OK - you should make that clear in the question, the instructions for Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 are very different.

Comment: Does the above apply only to XCode 4? If I update would that make it work?

Comment: Whoa. Just saw that Xcode 4 is a 4GB download. Hmmm.... do I have an alternative?

Comment: You should be fine using Xcode 3, you just need to specify that in your question so that you get the appropriate advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: Given that you've tagged this question with **iphone**, I'll assume you're building an iPhone app. In that case, you need to add libSoundCloudAPI.a as a direct dependency, but not SoundCloudAPI.framework.

To set the header search path in Xcode 3:

1. Ctrl-click your app's target (inside Targets in the Group & Files panel on the left hand side) and choose **Get Info**
2. Click the **Build** tab - these are the build settings! :-)
3. Set Configuration: to **All Configurations**, Show: to **All Settings**
4. In the **Search Paths** section, update Header Search Paths

Comment: Sorry, but I'm completely lost. The libSoundCloudAPI.a file is red in my XCode project. Is that okay? If not, how do I add it? And where do I find it's path? On another note, I'm currently building it and getting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179888/target-specifies-product-type-com-apple-product-type-framework

Comment: Red is fine. The error you're seeing is because you've added the .framework file as a dependency - they're not supported on iOS, you should add only libSoundCloudAPI.a as a direct dependency. The path is wherever you checked the SoundCloud git repository out to - if you've followed the instructions on the SoundCloud GitHub page it'll be in a folder called SoundCloudAPI inside your app's main folder, so the relative path is `SoundCloudAPI/`