# Target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, soundcloud

I'm trying to use a Soundcloud API wrapper for the iPhone following [these instructions](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper) and now I'm getting this error:

> target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SoundCloud API has two products:

- `SoundCloudAPI.framework` (a framework, for Mac OS X)
- `libSoundCloudAPI.a` (a static library, for iOS)

If you're building an app for iOS you need to add libSoundCloudAPI.a **only** as a direct dependency. You've added the framework as a dependency too, which is why you're getting this error.

Comment: I have the error message please help me  
                                     "target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform"