# Unable to load images from framework in my project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, frameworks

My project structure is in such a way that I have 2 projects named as `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. Now for these 2 projects, I have created a framework named as `ProjFramework`.

I have added common files of these 2 projects inside the framework and then added framework in the projects separately. Till now I am able to access all the files and vars. Now I added the images also in the framework and when I am trying to display them in UI then I am getting an error saying *unable to read this .png*.

As I know I need to include the framework somehow but I don't know how. Please help me in sharing common images b/w 2 `XCode` projects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you add images to the framework? as an `Asset` or just put your file?

Comment: For now I have kept them as png.

Comment: Try again by adding your images to "Build Phases" -> "copy files" of your `projFramework` settings.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before Building and distributing your `framework`, you should copy files that need to carry with your `framework`.

To copy files, Click your `framework project target`, go to "**Build Phases**" tab and you can see a section called "**Copy Files**". Add your files here(See below screenshot)

[image]

Then build your `framework project`, after a successful build your distributable framework will be generated in your **Products** folder. It will look like `YourFrameworkProjectName.framework`.

Add this file to other projects which need your framework.

**Note:** If you just want to run your project by connecting with your framework project, you can be done it by adding build dependency. [See StackOverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219054/xcode-adding-a-project-as-a-build-dependency)

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to @arunjos007' method is to (a) create a bundle of your images, then (b) retrieve from the bundle.

Let's say you have a Framework called *Kernel*, and you wish to access two types of files - *cikernel* and *png*.

**Creating a bundle:**

- Move all your files/images into a new folder on your desktop. Name it whatever you wish. In my example I named them *cikernels* and *images*.
- Rename your folders, with a *.bundle* extension. In my example they became *cikernels.bundle* and *images.bundle*. You will see the warning below... choose "Add".

[image: Bundle warning]

- Drag the bundle into your framework project. You can expand the bundle to see the contents. Also, you can add/delete/edit the contents of the bundle.

**Retrieving files from the bundle:**

I've created two public functions, one to retrieve files and one to retrieve images. They are pretty much the same, except for (a) the return type and (b) error handling. (I probably should add some to the `UIImage` function - but since I have total control on the code - it's not going to be used by anyone else - it's not critical.)

```
public func returnImage(_ named:String) -> UIImage {
    let myBundle = Bundle.init(identifier: "com.companyName.frameworkName")
    let imagePath = (myBundle?.path(forResource: "images", ofType: "bundle"))! + "/" + named
    let theImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
    return theImage!
}

public func returnKernel(_ named:String) -> String {
    let myBundle = Bundle.init(identifier: "com.companyName.frameworkName")
    let kernelPath = (myBundle?.path(forResource: "cikernels", ofType: "bundle"))! + "/" + named + ".cikernel"
    do {
        return try String(contentsOfFile: kernelPath)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        return error.description
    }
}
```

One last note: The *identifier* is defined in the Framework target's *General* tab. Typically it's in the form *com.company*framework*. Change that line to your's.

Comment: Can we access Assets.xcassets if we have Assets.xcassets inside images.bundle ?