# Importing Circular SeekBar to xcode project

Tags: ios, github

i am porting an app from android platform to ios.

I have used circular seekbar from github in my android project. [ArcSeek Bar](https://github.com/MarcinMoskala/ArcSeekBar)
using the dependency `compile 'com.github.marcinmoskala:ArcSeekBar:0.31'`

in my app level build gradle.

Now i need to use something like this in my ios project too. I have found a similar widget in ios too. [IOS circular seekbar](https://github.com/karthikkeyan/CircularSeek)

Now i have the question of how to import this widget to my project.. like in my android aplication.. is there a gradle file i should put some code or a url to import this.?

I am very new to ios development. Although i have 3 years of android experience i am 1 week into ios development.

Answer (score 0):

You should download this project and add it to your project. This is explained in this link below.

[Xcode : Adding a project as a build dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219054/xcode-adding-a-project-as-a-build-dependency)

After that follow the instruction provided by  iOS circular seekbar author